# Programmatic LUIS predict API returns 400 error

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

The **predict API** was working a week ago as I tested, but it suddenly stopped working this morning **(December 02, 2016)** with the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"
  }
}
```

The API Reference for this call is [here](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de479).

And this is the sample code I'm using:

```
static void Main()
{
    MakeRequest();
}

static async void MakeRequest()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "*****");
    var uri = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1.0/prog/apps/******/predict?" + queryString;
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test.");
    using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
    {
        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    }
}
```

Did anyone here have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is, but I just deleted the app and re-create and the problem gone.

Hope it helps someone passing by.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using the API and it's working for me. If I issue the request using "test." as in your sample code, I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Array of utterances cannot be null"
  }
}
```

However, when I change that to a json array like:

```
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("[ 'test.' ]");
```

it works just fine and I'm getting the predictions as expected

I would recommend you to update that line of code and see what happens.

Comment: thanks, I just tried but I still get the same error, and my error was "Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index". not "Parameter name: Array of utterances cannot be null". Any idea?

Comment: I know; I wasn't able to reproduce that error using exactly your code. Double check the app and subs key however I suspect you won't having that error if any of those are wrong